# CSS @font-face doesn't render

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm using the following code in the style sheet for my website, but it won't render when I run it in the browser, the font doesn't render.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@font-face {  
  font-family: 'Libel Suit';  
  src: url('my.ip.n.n/~/wordpress/fonts/libelsuit.woff') format('woff'),  
       url('my.ip.n.n/~/wordpress/fonts/libelsuit.ttf') format('truetype');  
       // These aren't the exact URLS I'm using, since I don't want the  
       // world to know my ip address
}
```

Comment: did you check if the fonts are actually loaded? also there is a possibility that there is an error with the fonts, so you'll have to convert them again maybe by using [fontsquirrel](http://fontsquirrel.com)

Comment: definitely use the fontsquirel webfont generator. takes care of everything

Comment: If you don’t want to disclose relevant data about the specific case, there is little hope of solving the case. There are plenty of questions like this, with answers that list down the possible issues in general.

Answer (score 0):

Check your [network panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) to determine if the fonts are actually being loaded:

[image]

If they are, ensure you are correctly referencing them in your css, e.g.:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Libel Suit'; 
}
```